# how can c# entity framework code first add table in code side

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I want to add a table on the coding side and create it in a live database.

Running the update database command on the code side

thx for help

Comment: And what did you try? Where are you stuck? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: İ dont known how can this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you consult the following documentation to know how to use the entity framework migration :

[Microsoft docs - Code First Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations)

If you want to have an automatic update of your database when launching the application, look at this section :

[Microsoft docs - Code First Migrations - Automatically Upgrading on Application Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#automatically-upgrading-on-application-startup-migratedatabasetolatestversion-initializer)

Comment: Can you describe problem or error you have ? Also, can you provide part of your code, especially the DbContext class ?

Comment: <code>Either the parameter objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (OBJECT) is wrong</code>

Comment: This error looks like a naming problem. Check that on your entities, the names of the class correspond to the name of the base tables. Same thing for properties with column names. If the names do not match, you can use "Table" and "Column" attributes. For example :


[Table("myTableName")]
public class MyClass
{
    [Column("myColumnName")]
    public string MyPropertie { get; set; }
.....
}